# What's the purpose and policy of this site?

Tags: discussion, answers, community, comments

Do we need, can we have, a topic which describes or summarizes the purpose and policies of this site?

Most people (including new users) don't seem to need one, i.e. they contribute questions and/or answers and there's no problem.

Occasionally there's a user who I, as a moderator, find slightly more problematic -- sometimes I feel like I have to keep telling them, well there's "this" rule, and there's "that" rule, and there's also the "other" rule ... and all the various rules aren't clear and in one place.

- There are rules in the Help about "Be nice" and about "comments" (how much to comment or not to comment), etc.; but there are many dozens of Help topics.
- And there were policies expounded in Meta, about what kinds of answers we do or don't want to see on this site, about how or even whether to express your disagreement with other answers (and/or with other schools), etc.; but there are nearly 300 Meta-topics.

---

We already have at least two [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) meta-topics:

- [Welcome to Buddhism.SE!](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1506/254) is mostly positive and mostly about asking questions.
- [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254) is again mostly positive and entirely about questions.

Whereas *this* topic might be more negative or prohibitive

It may be that what I'm asking for in this topic is a larger number of negative prohibitions than of positive permissions.
For example like there many prohitive 'rules' in a public swimming pool:

- What you *can* do: swim! and not swim.
- What you *cannot* do: spit, run, jump, fight, shoes, glass, etc.

---

I feel like I've written so much Meta-stuff already. Do I have to write more?

Can you say whether we need this topic, and if so what it should contain?

IMO some of the topic might be,

- Not too many comments ... see e.g. [Robin's summary](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1729/254),

  > And not having this back and forth "forum style" interaction is what makes this site special and different than other forums for some users. We seem to appreciate the neatness of simply providing an answer and leaving it at that as compared to being drawn into arguments via endless comments.
- Answers may not need references but should have some foundation in Buddhism
- Be nice
- Answers (not 'advice' instead of an answer)
- Use Meta not the main site, when you want to discuss the site
- Avoid being rude about 'other' schools of Buddhism

Comment: I thinks we need a FAQ like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites with site specific issues. Perhaps we can add a prominent link to this in our welcome message.

Comment: Also this would be interesting to go through: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta

Comment: Obviously this site is only for questions. For example, one cannot post an article one writes. Is that correct? Thanks. Also, is there a way to contact the moderators? Thanks

Comment: @Dhammadhatu `For example, one cannot post an article one writes. Is that correct?` Yes that's correct (see e.g. [this topic](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1784/254)). The site is primarily intended for questions-and-answers. `Also, is there a way to contact the moderators?` Yes, you can 'flag' anything (any question, andwer, or comment) that bothers you; and/or you can post a new question/topic on Meta, if you want to discuss something privately; and/or post a comment if you want a a moderator to create a private chat with you.