# I don't understand the reasoning behind this moderation

Tags: discussion, specific-question

From [this comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39558/a-path-to-another-university-outside-of-buddhism?noredirect=1#comment65785_39558)

> the only question mark in this Q is the link and reference to the link (which you closed). The other answer given also starts by pointing out that there is really no question posed. I don't understand the reasoning behind this moderation. I just wonder why this style is deemed ok as it is very unusual, it's a bare "share your thoughts on my situation request"

> I think i get the general issue OP is facing and i think community can help him so it's more of a formatting issue for me. I think this format isn't conducive to this Q/A being easily referenced in the future (avoiding duplicates etc), no tags, no question, bad title

Answer (score 1):

**I don't understand the reasoning behind this moderation.**

Well I agree I think it might be a poor question and not "deemed ok" ... or perhaps a fine question but one which is not really suited to the Q&A format of this site.

OTOH the previous question was worse and I closed that for two reasons:

1. It was asking, "Which is for me: Buddhism or Christianity?" -- which I think is a type of question which this site decided to agree to close or to consider unaskable, for reasons described here: [Which type of Buddhism is for me?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/254)
2. It meets the definition of a "broad comparison", which is defined in [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) as being one of the reasons for closing a question.

Conversely I didn't close this because -- although it is "too broad" and "unclear what you're asking" -- those are both defined (in the [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254)) as being *not* reasons to close a question ... on this site anyway, even though such a question would normally be closed on another SE site.

**I think i get the general issue OP is facing and i think community can help him**

I think that's a reason for allowing people to try to answer the question (instead of closing it).

You can also try to improve the question. I edited it slightly -- and I see you tried to improve the tags -- it didn't know what to do with the title however so I left that unedited and unquestioned (instead of continuing to complain about the OP's question, even so I've no idea what the word "university" is meant to be doing in the title).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain things. I don't have much to say because i understand your reasons, don't have anything to suggest and it's your call.

Comment: The community asked for a very liberal/permissive moderation policy for questions, so that's what there is.